# Remove all "words" that start with https when writing an arraylist to a text file

Tags: java, arraylist, twitter, hyperlink

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\markc\\OneDrive\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\TwitterTest\\src\\text\\output.txt");

for (int i = 0; i < tweetsArray.size(); i++) {
    writer.println(tweets.get(i).getText());
}
```

Here I am writing the contents of tweets.get(i).getText() line by line to a new text file called output.txt.

Some of the contents of these tweets contains links starting with "http", how would I remove all links from the text file?

Thanks
Example text file looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/omtbX.jpg

Comment: You should get all the content of the tweet and then split it in order to make an array with all the words, then using String regex you can not include again words starting with http or https

Comment: Can you post the code that you tried and some text example that contains `http` and how it should look like after removing the unnecessary parts?

Comment: Please post example file

Comment: Do you want the entire link removed or just the http part of the link?

Comment: I want the entire link removed please

Comment: Do any links contain spaces? Or are all links URL encoded (space = %20)? `http://test.com/I Like Pie.html` vs `http://test.com/I%20Like%20Pie.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from most of the answers, this is a game of choose your Regular Expression. This will work for URLs that don't contain white space, leaving the rest of the following tweet intact - `i like pie. http://pie.com is great` becomes `i like pie. is great`. Fiddle with it [here](http://fiddle.re/m7x6jn).

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\markc\\OneDrive\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\TwitterTest\\src\\text\\output.txt");
for (int i = 0; i < tweetsArray.size(); i++) {
     writer.println(tweets.get(i).getText().replaceAll("http\\S*", ""));
}
```

Edit:

For posterity, here is a slightly more efficient version that doesn't recompile the RegEx Pattern for every single tweet.:

```
PrinterWriter writer = new PrinterWriter("...");
Pattern linkPattern = Pattern.compile("http\\S*");
for(...) {
    writer.println(linkPattern.matcher(tweets.get(i).getText()).replaceAll(""));
}
```

Comment: @MarkChesser No worries. I added slightly better code under the Edit:. Don't forget to mark this as the answer if it's covering all your cases.

Comment: How would I extend this further and remove words starting with "@" as well?

Comment: You're looking for http or @. That is supported as well: `(http|@)` - the parenthesis group the pair of strings and the pipe is symbolically Or. Check out [Pattern javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\markc\\OneDrive\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\TwitterTest\\src\\text\\output.txt");
for (int i = 0; i < tweetsArray.size(); i++) {
     writer.println(tweets.get(i).getText().replaceAll("(?m)^http.*", ""));
}`
```

Comment: Can you explain how the ("(?m)^http.*", "") works please?

Comment: (?m): Turns multi-line mode on, so that the start-of-line ^ anchor matches the start of each line.
    ^: matches the start-of-line.
    http: Matches the literal http sequence.
    .* matches everything to the end of line.

Answer (score 0):

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\markc\\OneDrive\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\TwitterTest\\src\\text\\output.txt");

for (int i = 0; i < tweetsArray.size(); i++) {
            if(tweets.get(i).getText().indexOf("http") != 0 )
                writer.println(tweets.get(i).getText());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like regex might be the best way to do this. Sorry i don't know the specific pattern you'd need to capture everything but the link (which we can assume is anything between http and the next space). I'll update the post if i can figure it out, shouldn't be too difficult.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex pattern);
String line;
while ((line = reader.readline()) != null)
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    if (m.find())
        writer.write(m.group() + "\r\n");
```

Edit: not sure if this is the best way but it should work

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?)(?:http.*? )(.*$)");
String line;
while ((line = reader.readline()) != null)
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    if (m.find())
        writer.write(m.group(1) + m.group(2) + "\r\n");
```